# detect end of file in pyserial python3

Tags: serial-port, python-3.4, pyserial

I have been searching this, but couldn't get a good answer.

i have to send a file through COM port between two PC.

but i dont know how to detect the end of file.

In PC 1 i use teraTerm software to send file.

In PC 2 is use the following python code.

After the file is sent i need to put some message that the file is complete.

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('COM1')
ser.flush_input_buffer()
file = open('file.txt','a')       #open empty file for appending
while True:
    receivedByte = ser.read()      # read 1 byte
    file.write(receivedByte)
    if (#detect end of file ):
        break
print('file received')
```

Please note : PC is windows 8.1, Pyserial, Python 3.4

Please also suggest for Linux file

Answer (score 0):

There is no EOF for a serial port as such. And what I can gather from the Internet teraTerm doesn't have a protocol for sending files, but just sends them in their raw form.

You could maybe set the read timeout for the serial port, so that the `read` would raise a `SerialTimeoutException` when there is no data left.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this solution, although it is not as elegant and rather simple. It does work.

```
receivedByte = ser.read()         # read 1 byte
while receivedByte != b'':
    file.write(receivedByte)
    receivedByte = ser.read()

print('file received')
```